# Unable to get system properties from java code

Tags: java, tomcat

I have placed below code in catalina.sh for getting system properties, this is Apache Tomcat server.

```
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dserver=https://8.7.198.4"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dencoding=c3BhcmtDbGllbnQ6MGQ5YWJmMTdlYTiYWUyYWYyNzdhMzliOWZjNzk="
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dservice.url=/api/"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Dlogin.service=oauth7"
  JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Ddomain.name=nms.mixwoorks.net"

Tomcat Version       JVM Version    JVM Vendor          OS Name OS Version      
Apache Tomcat/7.0.29    1.6.0_33-b04    Sun Microsystems Inc.   Linux   2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
```

In the Java code, I'm using `System.getProperty("server");` to get the defined properties. But I'am getting null as value.

Comment: Did you mean `System.getProperty("server");`? Is the typo in your code or in your question?

Comment: @Bruno yes Bruno.Typo in question.Corrected

Comment: Corrected the question please

Comment: What you're trying to read are [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), not [environment variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html).

Comment: Ok, let me explain you clearly. I have customize the code, so iam giving options to client to set there own things for the above properties. So i put those properties in catalina.sh as environment variable and passing as key/value pair.Those will be used in code. so client can edit it set accordingly .

Comment: My point was about the terminology: system properties v.s. environment variables. `JAVA_OPTS` isn't an environment variable in `catalina.sh`. It's at best a shell variable, not visible as an env. variable from the JRE. It is indeed used to pass system properties as command-line options to your Java process.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15233/discussion-between-developer-and-bruno)

Comment: Did you try with System.getProperties http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()

Comment: Where are you put these configuration. You must put them where before you user them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the environment variable on your operating system, use `System.getenv()`

I am not sure I fully understand what you are doing here, but if you are trying to access variable that were defined in the shell script, then you should configure the environment variable properly in your script.

If you use tcsh / csh:

```
setenv PROP VALUE
```

If you use bash / sh:

```
PROP=VALUE
export PROP
```

Then PROP will be avilable from you java code.
Use:

```
System.getenv("PROP");
```

Hope it helps..